# how to break line in jsp from class file in struts

Tags: java, string, jsp, struts, line-breaks

Good day,

Below is part of my jsp code in campaignListing.jsp :

```
<td><bean:write name="row" property="campaignPeriod" /></td>
```

Below is part of my code in class files:

```
String cp = null;
cp= "From " + "<br>" + "To ";
cmForm.setCampaignPeriod(cp);  //set the campaignPeriod to display cp string
```

I have a td with `property="campaignPeriod"` in my jsp file.
I would like to make the "From" and "To" to display in 2 line in browser.

Would like to ask advise on how to make it. I tried put `"<br />"` , `"\n"` but it still displayed in 1 line only.

I am do in struts2 java project.

Comment: if i am correct`<bean:write>` is a tag from struts1 and not from struts2?

Comment: Ya, sorry my mistake. I will edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but you can try with `filter`

```
<bean:write name="row" property="campaignPeriod" filter="false"/>
```

this is what doc say about `filter`

> if this attribute is set to true, the rendered property value will be filtered for characters that are sensitive in HTML, and any such characters will be replaced by their entity equivalents.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. typo error in my code. the problem solve with filter="false" . Thanks.